# In MySQL, how can I find when a user has been linked to two specific groups?

Tags: mysql

A user can have multiple groups assigned to them, but I want to find only users that belong to two specific groups. How would I do that?

E.g. The user map table looks like this:

```
id | user_id | group_id
-----------------------
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 1       | 2
3  | 2       | 1
4  | 2       | 8
5  | 3       | 1
6  | 3       | 2
```

I want to get all users who belong to `group_id` with `1` and `2` only.

So the result would be:

```
id | user_id | group_id
-----------------------
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 1       | 2
5  | 3       | 1
6  | 3       | 2
```

I tried the following, but didn't work:

```
SELECT um.*
FROM user_map AS um
WHERE (group_id = '1' AND group_id = '2');
```

and

```
SELECT um.*
FROM user_map AS um
WHERE (group_id = '1' OR group_id = '2');
```

But got the wrong results.

Essentially I want to be able to `GROUP BY user_id` so that I have a list of just unique users that belong to group `1` or `2`.

Comment: what if user belong to three group 1, 2 and 5, should he be included in result?

Comment: Ideally no, however for my use case I don't think it would be an issue unless the users were assigned incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just the users, use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT um.user_id
FROM user_map  um
GROUP BY um.user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 AND
       SUM(group_id IN ('1', '2')) = 2;
```

This checks that there are two matching groups for a user and that those groups are exactly the ones you want.  This assumes that you do not have duplicates in the `user_map` table.

If you want the original rows, join in the original information:

```
SELECT um.*
FROM user_map um JOIN
     (SELECT um.user_id
      FROM user_map  um
      GROUP BY um.user_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 AND SUM(group_id IN ('1', '2')) = 2
     ) umm
     ON um.user_id = umm.user_id;
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot, and I like that you used `SUM()` in the having clause like that, since `WHERE group_id IN(1, 2)` would return multiple values (which I realized from testing).

Comment: I like it! Does exactly what I wanted, I need to do more testing with it first to make sure it always hits the mark. Could you explain a little bit about why this works? Since I know how to do complex queries, but I haven't come accross `HAVING` before, and didn't know you could use `SUM` in such a way.

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted to do, and I even added a left join with positive results. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I would ensure you have an index on your table on BOTH  (user_id, group_id).

Then do a self join and apply where clause to limit the first set to ensure at least the one group qualified, and the JOIN based on the second... only when BOTH instances exist are you good to go.  Yes, other approaches use COUNT(*), but I have always had good speed with this technique

```
SELECT 
      um.*
   FROM 
      user_map AS um
         JOIN user_map um2
            on um.user_id = um2.user_id
            AND um2.group_id = 2
   WHERE
      um.group_id = 1;
```

This way, say you had 1000 groups (exaggerated, but you will see why).  The outer WHERE clause is immediately jumping to only those who ARE AT LEAST in group_id = 1, then, the join to the second is only for those users who ALSO have the record for group_id = 2.

Comment: Nice, I do like the efficiency aspect, however the other statement is easier to do programmatically since I can create a for loop of entries to generate the `IN` statement.

Comment: @hazrpg, Agreed... but if you are only dealing with TWO, It is just a way to show some shortcuts without relying on COUNT(*) and HAVING COUNT(*)..

Comment: This is true. Your answer actually came in handy for me - I needed the efficiency this time instead of potentially multiples. So thanks you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let me know if this works

```
SELECT * FROM user_map WHERE group_id = '1' OR group_id = '2' 
GROUP BY (user_id);
```

Comment: That's essentially the statement I provided, with the `group by` added on which I did also try - the problem there is you still get user `1`, `2`, and `3` because user `2` is also part of group `1`. Thanks for your time though.